# How to call sendMFACode function from out of the authenticateUser function in aws cognito

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-sam

How to call the `sendMFACode` function from out of the `authenticateUser` function in the aws cognito

when i executing the `cognitoUser.sendMFACode`. i get following error

```
{ code: 'InvalidParameterException',
  name: 'InvalidParameterException',
  message: 'Missing required parameter Session' }
```

The executed code is

```
cognitoUser.sendMFACode('123456', {
                onSuccess: function (result) {
                   console.log(result);
                },
                onFailure: function (err) {
                   console.log(err);
                }
            })
```

`cognitoUser.getSession()` works only for authenticated user

```
Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
```

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: I temporarily saved the session value in the database and assigned
like this
`var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
  cognitoUser.Session = saved_session_value;`